# tikz rectangle inscribed in a rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I convert this into latex tikz?

[image]

Also, I want to insert the length (2x + 6) and width (x+6) of the bigger rectangle with arrow.
I'm newbie on LaTeX. Answers are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you provide the code as a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of what you have tried so far?

Comment: So far it's like this: \begin{tikzpicture} \draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (6, 4);\draw[very thick] (1, 1) rectangle (5,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: It would be helpful in the future to edit your post so that it includes your example. Please keep in mind to add a documentclass, all required packages as well as a `\begin{document}` and `\begin{document}` so that people that want to help you just can copy your example and compile it without having to guess anything.

And welcome to to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

This is a completely hard coded example, there might be better solutions that are more elegant and can be updated more easily if the proportions of the rectangle change:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    % rectangles
    \draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (6, 4) [fill=gray]; % gray rectangle
    \draw[very thick] (1, 1) rectangle (5,3) [fill=white]; % white rectangle
    
    % outer dimensions
    \draw[thick, <->] (3,0) -- (3,1) node [midway,right] {3}; % bottom
    \draw[thick, <->] (3,3) -- (3,4) node [midway,right] {3}; % top
    \draw[thick, <->] (0,2) -- (1,2) node [midway,above] {3}; % left
    \draw[thick, <->] (5,2) -- (6,2) node [midway,above] {3}; % right
    
    % inner dimensions
    \node[below] at (3,3) {$2x$}; % top
    \node[left] at (5,2) {$x$}; % right
    
    % complete dimensions
    \draw[thick, <->] (0,4.5) -- (6,4.5) node [midway,above] {$2x+6$}; % top
    \draw[thick, <->] (6.5,0) -- (6.5,4) node [midway,right] {$x+6$}; % right
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you're right, thanks for the information, I already corrected it!

Comment: For the two exterior arrows, you could use |<->| to produce arrows with bars on the end.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for the information!

Comment: It is working. Thank you!